# Prove if two probability measures agree on a collection of subsets, they agree on the sigma-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $S = \{a,b,c,d\}, \mathcal{F}= 2^{\{a,b,c,d\}}, \mathcal{F} = σ(\mathcal{C})$.

1. What is the example of two distinct probability measures $P_1$ and $P_2$ agree on $\mathcal{C}$, a collection of sets? Here $\mathcal{C} = \{\{a,b\},\{c,d\},\{a,c\},\{b,d\}\}$.
2. $(S, \mathcal{F})$ a measurable space, and $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under finite union. How to prove that two measures $P_1$ and $P_2$ agree on $\mathcal{C}$ also agree on $\mathcal{F}$?
3. Can I still prove that they also agree on $\mathcal{F}$, if $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under complements? Or is there other counterexample?

Comment: I edited your question, but may not have distinguished your two Fs ($F$ and $\mathcal{F}$ in my edit) correctly

Comment: Thanks for your edit. There is only one F, and it always refers to sigma-field.

Comment: In your original version you had both "F= 2^{a,b,c,d}" and "F = σ(C)"

Comment: Oh, I meant F = 2^{a,b,c,d} = σ(C).

Comment: $\mathcal C$ as defined is not closed under finite union. So the $\mathcal C$ under 2) is differs from the defined?

Comment: @drhab Yes. Sorry again for not clarifying it. $\mathcal{C}$ = $\{\{a,b\},\{c,d\}, \{a,c\}, \{b,d\}\}$ is only for 1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) example:

$P_1(\{x\})=\frac14$ for $x\in\{a,b,c,d\}$.

$P_2(\{x\})=\frac18$ for $x\in\{a,d\}$ and $P_2(\{x\})=\frac38$ for $x\in\{b,c\}$.

2) Define $\mathcal E:=\{A^c\mid A\in\mathcal C\}$. Then $\mathcal E$ is a [$\pi$-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_system) with $\sigma(\mathcal E)=\sigma(\mathcal C)=\mathcal F$.

Also $\mathcal E$ is contained in [$\lambda$-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_system#Relationship_to_.CE.BB-Systems) $\mathcal D:=\{A\in\wp(S)\mid P_1(A)=P_2(A)\}$ so that $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathcal D$.

3) The $\mathcal C$ under 1) is closed under complements and satisfies $\sigma(\mathcal C)=\mathcal F$, so serves as counterexample.

Comment: I appreciate your kind answer.
1. Could you elaborate on 1)?
2. How could I imply the closure under finite union at $\mathcal{E}$?
3. So 3) works. What can be the general proof? Is it similar to 2)?

Comment: Actually, I could not quite understand the definition of "agree on", as I have just begun prob theory this semester. So it does not mean $P_1 = P_2$?

Comment: 2) There is no closure of finite union at $\mathcal E$ but there is closure of intersection. If $A^c,B^c\in\mathcal E$  then $A^c\cap B^c=(A\cup B)^c\in\mathcal E$. In general $P_1,P_2$ agree on $\mathcal V$ means that $P_1(V)=P_2(V)$ is true for every $V\in\mathcal V$.

Comment: Oh, so In this example $P_1 =P_2$ because $P_1(\{x\})=P_2$ for $x ∈ \{b,c\} - P_2$ for $x ∈ \{a,b\} = 1/4$?

Comment: In this example $P_1\neq P_2$ since $P_1(\{a\})=\frac14\neq\frac18=P_2(\{a\})$ (so $P_1$ and $P_2$ are distinct, as requested). But it can be proved that $P_1(C)=P_2(C)$ for every $C\in\mathcal C$ (so $P_1,P_2$ agree on $\mathcal C$ as requested).

Comment: Thank you. I think I rather confused you more as well. Last (perhaps) question: Could you describe the difference between $P_1$ and $P_1(C)$ please? I realized I should be very cautious when I write the notation. The proof of $P_1(C)=P_2(C)$ is relevant to my post too?

Comment: Measure $P_1$ must be looked at as a function on sets. If $C$ is such a set then it is an argument for $P_1$ and $P_1(C)$ denotes the probability of $C$ under $P_1$. The same sort of difference between as a function $f$ prescribed by $x\mapsto x^2$ and value $f(3)=9$. You are asked to find distinct probability measures $P_1,P_2$ that agree on $\mathcal C$. If you come up with $P_1,P_2$ then of course you must show that these conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Understanding that you are a beginner on probability theory I advice you not to accept my answer. This because I use advanced material to prove 2) ($\pi$- and $\lambda$-systems). I hope that someone else will answer this without using it.

Comment: Could you maybe add the algebraic steps to get 1/4, 1/8, and 3/8 at the first question part in detail?

Comment: My thinking: "Let's take $P_1$ uniform. Now how to construct a non-uniform $P_2$ such that $P_2(C)=\frac12=P_1(C)$ for every $C\in\mathcal C$? Well, for at least one of the singletons it must be true that $P_2(\{x\})\neq\frac14$. Let's try it with $P_2(\{a\})=\frac18$ then, and let's see what happens..."

Comment: I finally understood why 1) can be used as the counterexample for 3). I should have slept more. I appreciate you again!

Comment: I am sorry accepting your answer a little bit late! Thank you very much again.